# How to see packages included in Ubuntu kit?

Tags: wireless, drivers, 14.04, software-installation

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 13.10 to Ubuntu 14.04.

I think I'm having a problem with my wireless drivers, in that every hour or so, my connection drops, and I can't see my local network. What fixes this is me deactivating  and reactivating the wireless connections.

I'd like to install the driver that I previously had on 13.10, and I thought that if I could see what driver that was, it would be a starting point.

Is what I’m trying to do possible, and if so, how would I check what drivers are included in the default Ubuntu installation?

Comment: Depending on the wireless card, the driver is built into the kernel. You can try an alternate kernel or check your logs for errors and debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out that, if you mount the DVD (for 13.04 at least), you're going to have a firectory called `casper`

Inside it, you'll have a file called `filesystem.manifest` that contains a list of all packages (and their versions) included in the distribution - as far as I can tell.